# how to insert file contents on match using sed - first occurrence only

Tags: text-processing, sed

file contents:

```
# cat file.txt 
-----
MATCH
-----
MATCH
-----
MATCH
-----

# cat text.txt 
add this text file
before first match
```

sed commands:

```
# sed '0,/MATCH/r text.txt' file.txt
-----
add this text file
before first match
MATCH
add this text file
before first match
-----
MATCH
-----
MATCH
-----

# sed '0,/MATCH/i prependme once' file.txt
prependme once
-----
prependme once
MATCH
-----
MATCH
-----
MATCH
-----
```

I'm trying to merge these commands somehow to get the following output:

```
-----
add this text file
before first match
MATCH
-----
MATCH
-----
MATCH
-----
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `ed` instead of `sed`

```
ed -s << EOF file.txt
0,/MATCH/-1 r text.txt
,p
q
EOF
```

or as a one-liner

```
printf '0,/MATCH/-1 r text.txt\n,p\nq' | ed -s file.txt
-----
add this text file
before first match
MATCH
-----
MATCH
-----
MATCH
-----
```

(replace `,p` by `w` for in-place editing).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$ sed '0,/MATCH/ s/MATCH/add this text file\nbefore first match\nMATCH/' file.txt
```

or just use other sed expression for your output

```
$ sed '0,/MATCH/i prependme once' file.txt | sed 1d
```

for adding file content

```
$ sed -e '0,/MATCH/s/MATCH/$(cat text.txt)\nMATCH/' file.txt
```

Other possible solution using `-----` as your matching string

```
$ sed '0,/-----/r text.txt' file.txt
```